# Can't access parent class methods in a JUnit test case

Tags: java, unit-testing, inheritance, junit

I'm trying to test an abstract class "Comando" which has a few dozen inherited classes. What I actually want to test are the many different chuld classes, to test each different behaviour ("Comando" translates to Command), and my test case is something like:

```
public void testComandoGetInfo() {
    ComandoGetInfo cmd = new ComandoGetInfo(equip);
    equip.executarComando(cmd, true, true);
    cmd.getStatus();
}
```

Notice the line `cmd.getStatus()`. When I write this line NetBeans gives me a "method not found" compilation error. When I toggle code completion, I can't see any of Comando's methods, only the TestCase testing methods and the single method that's on ComandoGetInfo class.

ComandoGetInfo is a class that extends Comando, which have many, many methods and variables, both public and private.

So why can't I access any method (I mean ANY, even getters, setters, public methods or variables, anything, not even static ones) of the parent class Comando, and how to test it if I can't?

**EDIT:** Found what the error was. I simply had my test class named exactly as my original class, so the test class for the Comando.java was... Comando.java, in the same package of the test folder. Everything came back to normal after I renamed the file to the correct name "ComandoTest.java".

Comment: Are you *sure* you've made `ComandoGetInfo` extend `Comando`?

Comment: I've been developing this software for over an year now, yes I'm sure.

Comment: what is the visibility of the getters and setters? is the test case in the same package as commando?

Comment: Can you please include the code for you abstract and example child class please?  Kind of hard to tell otherwise

Comment: Sorry guys, I found the error, I'll edit the question explaining it :S

Comment: Maybe answer the question then?